# Syntax error or access violation: 1139 Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexp

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have this regex:

```
REGEXP '(^0+|0+)17198671(0+|$)$'
```

which needs to match strings like these

```
US00171986710
00171986710000000000000
001719867100000000
```

basically what i need is that if the string has all the same numbers in it replacing the zeroes and ending with zeroes or nothing, I want to match them. I don't understand why this valid regex doesn't work with MySQL

Comment: `(0+|)` is just a fancy way of writing `0*`.

Comment: This is equivalent `0+171986710*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL regex engine does not allow empty alternatives, like in `ab(c|)` or `a|`. The `(0+|$)` part matches either 1+ zeros or an empty string at the input string end, and this causes an error.

Note that `(^0+|0+)` means that one or more zeros do not have to appear at the start of the string, hence all you need is

```
REGEXP '0+171986710*$'
```

**Details**

- `0+` - one or more `0`s
- `17198671` - a literal substring
- `0*` - zero or more `0`s
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I was very tired when I wrote this. Thanks for simplifying it for me though!

Comment: had this problem with mysql 5+ but not mysql 8

Comment: @sg552 That is because in MySQL 8.x regular expressions are handled by the [ICU regex engine](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Do you know what to replace `OR` in mysql regex? For example : `AND CONCAT(",", `user_group_ids`, ",") REGEXP ",(35|43),"`.

Notice the `|`. Thanks in advance

Comment: @sg552 No idea what you mean, the `|` is an alternation operator that works in both flavors well.